# Storing an API Response in a Service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to store an API response in a service so I can access it across my views.

Here's the function in my service. It works perfectly when accessed via my controller, but I only want to run this API call once and then store the result in a service singleton. I'm using the Javascript API of https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/client/javascript to access user info.

```
getUser: function() {

  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var promise = authorizationResult.me().done(function(user_info) {
      username = user_info.alias // username is defined outside of function
      deferred.resolve(user_info);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
    }
```

and then I have the storage function:

```
storeUser: function() {
        return username;
    },
```

I've been playing around with it, and in my latest attempt I've tried to call the getUser() method through another factory. The important part is that I want to only call getUser() once. And then in my controller I want to rely on storeUser() to access the data I need.

This is the current getUser() call in my controller:

```
twitterService.getUser().then(function(data){  // I need to change this to storeUser()
      $scope.datapls(data.alias);
    });
```

Thanks! And I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use $cookiesStore of Angularjs for this. Inject $cookiesStore in your Service.
Then When u call your API For First Time Store username in cookies like this 

//Add Cookie Storing Code in Your Function
getUser: function() {

       var deferred = $q.defer();
       var promise = authorizationResult.me().done(function(user_info) {
       username = user_info.alias // username is defined outside of function
       $cookies.userName=username// Storing UserName in Cookies....
       deferred.resolve(user_info);
   });
  return deferred.promise;
 }

//Change Your Storage Function Like This
storeUser: function() {
    return $cookies.userName; //Return Username Stored in Cookies 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I expanded upon the other factory idea.

I call the getUser() function with this factory

```
app.factory('InitEverything', function(twitterService, $q) { 

twitterService.initialize();
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var promise = twitterService.getUser().then(function(data) {
            console.log("init ran");
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

   return deferred.promise;
});
```

And then I call that call InitEverything from my controller as follows:

```
InitEverything.then(function(){
  if (twitterService.isReady()) {
     $scope.userhandle = twitterService.storeUser();  
     $scope.datapls($scope.userhandle);
  } 
});
```

So it looks like I needed to chain 2 promises together so the async call from getUser() -> storeUser() would load with the controller.